# Create a sliding navbar in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add CSS to my navbar so that when the user scrolls down the navbar background will slide from the top. Right now the background is just appearing with no transition. What am I missing?

Here's what I have written for jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        const $nav = $(".navbar");
        $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
     });
});
```

SCSS:

```
.navbar { 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;

    &.scrolled { 
        background-color: #FDFDFD;
        transition: background-color top 1s;
        padding-bottom: 24px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
   <navbar class="grid-1">
      <img class="navbar-logo" src="#" alt="Website">
         <a class="navbar-links-li-1" href="#">Workshops</a> 
         <a class="navbar-links-li-2" href="#">Resources</a> 
         <a class="navbar-links-li-3" href="#">Donate</a> 
   </navbar>
</div>


<section class="main grid-1">
  <p>blah</p>
</section>
```

Comment: "*What am I missing?*" Well right now you are missing the rest of the code from your question  that we need :) Please include your *relevant code* (and only the relevant code)in a [**minimal, reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Comment: Oh sorry! I've readded a link to JSFiddle that has my current code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a **`transition` rule** to the `navbar` class, e.g. to set transitions on all properties for a duration of 0.5 seconds, use the following:

```
.navbar {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    // the rest of your CSS
}
```

Take a look at [this CSS transitions page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for more information.

**Working example** using the minimum of your code to illustrate the effect:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        const $nav = $(".navbar");
        $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
     });
});
```

```css
.navbar { 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: #ccc;
 }
 .scrolled { 
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
    transition: background-color top 1s;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {height:1000px; padding-top:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">NAV BAR </div>
<div class="content">
<p>Stuff here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohhhh, amazing! Thank you, and thanks for providing me with the CSS page as well :)

Comment: @imnewhere Glad to help! You can do lots with CSS transitions so I thought the page might be useful :)